# Jquery Conflict issue for slider tab

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery carousel tab slider for my project. But i am getting some issue, that is when I click on the **Featured products** the slider goes down and stops working.

Please see [link](http://dev.genuusdemo.com/bigbazaar/) for your reference

Also see the js fiddle for the html
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq2pys5y/)

See the JScode:-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    addOnload(function () {
        BIGB.utils.runOnload();
    });
    addWindowOnload(function () {
        BIGB.utils.runWindowOnload();
    });
    require_module.init({ "carousel": { "url": "slider/carousel-e1e730d.js" } });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require_module.js("carousel", function () {
        $(".require-nav-carousel").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var params = {
                content: $('.ccarousel', $this),
                buttonOverlap: true
            };
            var parsed_params = $this.data();
            $.extend(params, parsed_params);
            var navCarousel = new BIGB.ui.Carousel(params);
            navCarousel.init();
            $this.removeClass("require-nav-carousel");
        });
    });
    BIGB.linkTracking.setContext("hp");
    $('.bannerHolder').each(function () {
        $(this).mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hoverIn').removeClass('hoverOut').removeClass('noTransition');
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hoverOut').removeClass('hoverIn').addClass('noTransition');
        });
    });
    (function () {
        var $window = $(window);
        $window.bind('scroll', _.throttle(enableChristmasSaleUnit, 200));
        $window.bind('resize', _.throttle(enableChristmasSaleUnit, 200));
        var $saleUnit = $('.sticky-unit');
        function enableChristmasSaleUnit() {
            requestAnimFrame(function () {
                var st = $window.scrollTop();
                if (st > 200) {
                    !$saleUnit.hasClass("sticky-unit-active") && $saleUnit.addClass("sticky-unit-active");
                } else {
                    $saleUnit.hasClass("sticky-unit-active") && $saleUnit.removeClass("sticky-unit-active");
                }
            });
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: @APAD1: did u checked other things also ? may be some conflict issue..

Comment: I visited the dev page, let the slider rotate a few times, clicked "Featured Products," slider is still visible and is still rotating. Maybe I am misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: @APAD1: but for me when I clicked the "Featured Products" the slider images are coming down, See here http://imgur.com/K34CVBA

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now.

Comment: See here http://imgur.com/K34CVBA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70731/discussion-between-apad1-and-priyanka).